# How to query records that are scoped to the most recent record per association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a `Mark` model which has many `mark_allocations`

I need to find the number of `mark_allocations` that are correct, i.e.

`MarkAllocation.where(status: :correct).count`

However I only want to query from the most recent mark_allocations per mark.

I have already achieved this in ruby land like so:

```
MarkAllocation
  .order(created_at: :desc)
  .uniq(&:mark_id)
  .select { |m| m.correct? }
  .size
```

However this has become a performance bottleneck and I would like to do the selection at database level.

So far in my efforts I can get distinct records per mark no problem, but I am struggling to apply an order to get the most recent records per mark. I also have no idea how to go from that point, to further querying for only correct mark_allocations.

I have come up with this:

```
MarkAllocation
  .select(:mark_id, :state, :created_at)
  .order(created_at: :desc)
  .distinct(:mark_id)
  .where(state: :correct)
  .count(:mark_id)
```

But I know it is not correct and I can see the ORDER clause is missing from the raw sql it outputs.

EDIT:

Here is an example of how it is currently working with the ruby cody.

```
mark_allocations = [
  {mark_id: 1, status: :correct, created_at: 2.days.ago},
  {mark_id: 1, status: :incorrect, created_at: 1.day.ago},
  {mark_id: 2, status: :correct, created_at: 1.day.ago}
]

mark_allocations = mark_allocations.order(created_at: :desc).uniq(&:mark_id)
=> [  
  {mark_id: 1, status: :incorrect, created_at: 1.day.ago},
  {mark_id: 2, status: :correct, created_at: 1.day.ago}
]

mark_allocations = mark_allocations.select { |m| m.correct? }
=> [{mark_id: 2, status: :correct, created_at: 1.day.ago}]

mark_allocations.size
=> 1
```

Comment: You have two correct mark_allocations there, both corresponding to a different mark_id, so you'll have two records, not one. Is what you say "_However I only want to query from the most recent mark_allocations per mark._", what's your argument to say it should be just one if you want them "per mark".

Comment: Newer mark_allocations replace old mark_allocations. The mark_allocation that was created 2 days ago has since been replaced by an incorrect mark_allocation, so when I query the number of correct mark_allocations, I should only count the mark_allocation with mark_id: 2.  If you look at my ruby solutions.you can see I uniq the records *before* selecting the correct ones. That means not all correct ones are counted.

Comment: Hi James, like Sebastian, I'm not sure I understand why you'd only count `mark_id: 2` in the above array to get 1. Your previous queries get the unique/distinct mark_id and that would still give you a count of two. I would understand it giving you one if you used distinct on another column... maybe an association or something. Would you be able to clarify that, please?

Comment: Hi @John, I have edited my question showing an example of how the ruby code works, hopefully that clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

This would be one of those cases where you'd have to get your hands dirty with some SQL.

In PostgreSQL, you would need a query like this to get the records:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT ON (mark_id) *
         FROM (
                  SELECT *
                  FROM marks
                  ORDER BY created_at DESC
              ) m
     ) mm
WHERE status = 1;
```

This is assuming `1` is the enum integer for your correct state.

Or, this to get the count from those records:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT ON (mark_id) *
         FROM (
                  SELECT *
                  FROM marks
                  ORDER BY created_at DESC
              ) m
     ) mm
WHERE status = 1;
```

I would paste that into my MarkAllocation model with something like:

```
def self.counts
  query = <<-SQL.strip_heredoc
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM (
               SELECT DISTINCT ON (mark_id) *
               FROM (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM marks
                        ORDER BY created_at DESC
                    ) m
           ) mm
      WHERE status = #{states[:correct]};
  SQL
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query)
end
```

Sure it doesn't look pretty but it'll be more performant.

If you want the actual unique records, you could do something like:

```
def self.records
  nested_sql = MarkAllocation.all.order(created_at: :desc).to_sql
  query = <<-SQL.strip_heredoc
      SELECT *
      FROM (
               SELECT DISTINCT ON (mark_id) *
               FROM (
                        #{nested_sql}
                    ) m
           ) mm
      WHERE status = #{states[:correct]};
  SQL
  find_by_sql(query)
end
```

The records example above shows how you might have ActiveRecord generate the nested SQL and how you would use `find_by_sql` to transform the results into MarkAllocation ActiveRecord results.